# Not able to provide Git-Repositories with Apache to remote clients

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, git

I have X Git-Repositories on a Debian Server and want to provide them via Apache. I also want to use the Redmine Authentication with the Repositories, but I would be even great, if I could access the repositories.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName 192.168.1.2 (not the real ip
       # ServerAlias git
        ServerAdmin service-system@xxxx.xx

        PassengerEnabled off
        PassengerHighPerformance off

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/lib/git/
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

# Das Remine Perl Authentification muss in den Perl lib Baum gesymlinked sein
        # PerlLoadModule  Authen::Simple::LDAP
        PerlLoadModule  Apache::Redmine
        PerlLoadModule  IO::Socket::SSL
        <Location />
#                DAV svn
#                LimitXMLRequestBody 0
#                SVNParentPath "/var/lib/svn
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Satisfy any
                #     Browsen geht leider nicht
                #     SVNListParentPath On
#                SVNPathAuthz off
                PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
                PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
                AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user
                AuthName "Git Repository"
                AuthUserFile /dev/null

                <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
                        Require valid-user
                        Allow from 192.168.1.2
                        Allow from 127.0.0.1
                       Satisfy any
                </Limit>
                # write
                <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
                        Require valid-user
                </LimitExcept>
                RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine;host=127.0.0.1"
                RedmineDbUser "redmine"
                RedmineDbPass "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#               RedmineCacheCredsMax 100
        RedmineGitSmartHttp yes
        </Location>
```

The Git-Repositories are under /var/lib/git. But it does not matter how I do change this config, I am always between "Repository not found" and "Error 500". The Log-Files have not provided me with informations which would be helpful. Does someone have an idea?

(The OS is Debian 7.9)

Edit 2 :

I cannot get the authentication of the system to work, it is not even asking me about a password or a username:

This is the configuration so far, could someone tell me what i did wron?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>


LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so

DocumentRoot /var/lib/git
ServerName gittest

PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/lib/git
####SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/git-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/git-access.log combined


 ScriptAlias / /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/
<Location "/var/lib/git/">
    DAV on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "GM Git Repositories"
    Require valid-user

    PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
    PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler

  RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=myredminedb;host=localhost"
  RedmineDbUser "redmine"
  RedmineDbPass "passwort"
 # RedmineGitSmartHttp yes


    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache.key
....
</Location>
```

Comment: What are the permissions for `/var`, `/var/lib` and `/var/lib/git`?

Comment: ls -l / |grep var
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Nov 30 12:03 var
root@debian-redmine:/var/lib/git/fghf.git# ls -l /var/ |grep lib
drwxr-xr-x 57 root     root     4096 Dec  1 09:54 lib
root@debian-redmine:/var/lib/git/fghf.git# ls -l /var/lib |grep git
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data      www-data      4096 Dec  7 13:27 git BUT even if i change it into www-data:www-data I still get the error